# java.nio channels buffers streams terminology

Tags: java, terminology, nio

Does anybody have a good analogy (or, failing that, a good resource) for describing the relationships between buffers, streams, readers, channels, selectors etc. in java.io and java.nio?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this for a decent summary

[Java.nio vs Java.io](http://blogs.oracle.com/slc/2009/06/javanio_vs_javaio.html)

Further reading can be done here

[JDK 1.4.2 New I/O APIs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/nio/)

[A critical view at Java I/O](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/07/03/jsr-203-new-file-apis.html)

[JSR 51: NEW I/O API's](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=51)

[JSR 203: More new I/O APIs (inactive)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=203)

[Actual work on JSR 203 for JDK 7](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/) (should alread be in JDK7 since M2)

Comment: Thanks, the train example at the end of the first reference is the type of thing I am looking for...

Answer (score 0):

This is the best one I've found so far: [The Rox Java NIO Tutorial](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/index.html)

Comment: The ROX NIO tutorial is garbage. Guy doesn't even know that closing the channel cancels the key, and he invents a lot of non-existent difficulties about other things as well.